# Issue with getting form to submit with template

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to create a new form to register for an event that I am hosting.

I have successfully created the form, but when I submit the form it seems the wrong path is being called.

I have a feeling the error lies in this line of code.

```
url: "./././mail/contact_80.php",
```

When I attempt to submit the form I get the following message in the console
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" Which makes sense due to the location of the file that it is trying to load which is, https://www.vintonems.org/80th/mail/contact_80.php this is not the correct location of this file. The correct location is mail/contact_80.php

How can I make this point to the correct location? Please let me know if you need any other information.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Try write in the url the correct and complete url to file.

Comment: @Weber I have tried that. It seems the file was able to be accessed but the message never seemed to send.

Comment: did you check the permission?